# Create a computer trust between a Client (windows 7) and Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, active-directory

**Problem:**
Cannot log in because
"the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

There is no local Admin login.

Usually you can log in to an account that previously logged into (cashed account) We don't have a password for that account.

**Notes:**
I know that you can manually create computer accounts in active directory.

**Question:**
After that computer account is created is there a way to create the trust again?

Thanks

Comment: There is no local admin logon, or you don't have the local admin logon? Does anyone have the local admin logon?

Comment: no that is apart of the problem, before me there was no standard for creating a local admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't join a client to a domain without local admin rights on the client. Maybe you need to [look for ways of recovering the administrator account](https://superuser.com/search?q=lost+administrator+password+windows+7)?

Comment: The accepted answer for the post below is an accepted answer here thank you.

This worked with windows7 I could not change the password but I could clear it. 
superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password

Answer (score 0):

You say that you usually log in with a cached account.  It the Client on a different network from the Server?  If its on the same network, using cached credentials should be unnecessary.

Do you see the computer acct in AD on the server?  Is it locked/disabled?

Usually the way you create the 'trust' is to login to the client, and join the domain.  This will require an domain acct with the correct permissions to add a machine to the domain, ie a member of the Domain Admins group, etc.

Maybe it has changed in Win 7, but I thought there was always a Local Admin Login.

Comment: There is a local admin login (Administrator) but it is disabled by default. The cached account would be the domain login.

If I had the password from the previous domain login I could login in and remove the computer from the domain and add it back, reestablishing the client/domain trust

But I can't do anything with the computer domain-wise because their is no trust. Unless I am completely missing the point.